# How to do simple server side validation with Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to use Ace Editor to achieve:

1. Simple color coded syntax highlight
2. Server side validation and then mark some lines with errors using:

   editor.session.setAnnotations([{row:1 ,column: 0, text: 
   "message",type:"error"}]);

I want to parse a new language that is parsed "line by line" and is something like this:

```
A. GO TO 20
B. TURN LEFT
```

I already have a server side validator for my language (a Java lib) and I already achieved my 1. goal

My doubt is how to integrate everything for my second goal. Does the ace editor provide some functionality like this (server side validation)?

I saw this on github: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js that looks some kind of external validation for JS but I really don't understand if Ace provides something like I want or not.

In case ACE doesn't support it, how can I achieve this? If you can't provide the full example some high-level "architectural" tips would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Ace doesn't have an example of a validator that sends stuff to the server, but it runs validator in webworker which is somewhat similar.

The naive approach to the problem would be to add change listener to the session, and on every change send session contents to the server, run validator, send back json with error locations, and use `setAnnotations` the way you show in your question.

But sending whole document on every change is slow so ace sends only the changes, and rebuilds document from that.

**How ace works?:**
The modes have [createWorker](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/json.js#L73) function which creates instance of [WorkerClient](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/worker/worker_client.js#L39), WorkerClient starts webWorker and adds [changeListener](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/worker/worker_client.js#L165) to the document.
[worker.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/worker/worker.js#L174) uses [mirror.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/worker/mirror.js#L17) to reconstruct document from the changes, and call a function after timeout. All the language specific part is in that function. See [json_worker.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/json_worker.js#L48) if you somehow find it hard to understand `javascript_worker.js`

If you don't want to go with naive approach, You can reuse some of ace webWorker code to synchronize with the server. For client you'll need to replace postMessage in `worker_client.js` with send over socket, and for server use nodejs or reimplement `mirror.js` in java.

However reimplementing validation for your language in js and using it similar to jshint in javascript_worker will provide better user experience. You can even use a [java to js compiler](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js#javajvm) for that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about using a java to js compiler... My problem is the syntax highlighter format of Ace editor (that I don't understand yet).  Also, can you provide a more concrete answer to the problem? I tried reading the javascript worker and syntax highlighter but it seems they still use the JS syntax highlighter rules and stuff like that which makes it a bit hard to understand. It's not a simple example like I require: send stuff to server, get back lines in error, add error...

Comment: Hmm, I've got the impression like you didn't even try to read my answer:(, did you even look into worker folder? Anyway, I've updated it to something, hopefully more useful for you. If you are ok with sending whole document on every change, then it is extremely simple just an xhr call, and some code on your server to handle it. But it would work much better if you could move validation to client, e.g. by using java to js compiler to convert your Java lib to js.